# Toolbar background becomes white color when set to transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

There are a lot of questions about making transparent toolbar. but none of the given answers have solved my problem.

my issue here is that,i want to make transparent toolbar and it should has primary color background only when user scrolled up or down. But initially it has to be transparent until scroll up/down event occurred.

for that i have following theme:

```
<resources>   
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
        <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
          <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
          <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
          <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
          <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
          <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
           <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        </style>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
...
/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        .....

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       ....
       .... />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      ....
      ....
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But instead of getting transparent toolbar, i got a toolbar with white background.

can you please check what is wrong in my theme.xml?

I am using design support library 23.1.1
Thanks

Comment: have you tried removing the background atrribute? also create a theme without any primary colors and set it in your coordinator or toolbar.

Comment: yes .. but still i get white background

Comment: initially you need transparent background and while user scrolls you need primary color. ? am i correct

Comment: For my case it is still an issue.